# if parentViewContoller statement

Tags: objective-c, iphone, syntax, if-statement, parentviewcontroller

I'm writing a program with a UITableView with and add button in the Navigation Bar which leads to an edit page. When you click on an item in the table, a view (rView) is pushed with information pertaining to that item. This view has an edit button that also leads to the edit page.  Is there a way that I could put an if statement for the done button on the edit page that says "if parentViewController is the UITableView to go to rView, else popViewController?" I would assume there is a way to do this, but I'm not sure of the syntax to do so. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you have a UINavigationController and push onto it

1. a UITableView
2. an "rViewController" (you can't push a view, must be a controller)
3. an "EditController"

But there is a possibility that step 2 is omitted and you go directly to the edit screen.

Now when the last controller is popped, you want to be able to *always* go to a "rViewController", even if it's not on the stack.

First of all, the parentViewController is NOT the previous controller on the stack, but rather the UINavigationController itself, so it has nothing to do with the present problem.

The way to do this is by setting the UINavigationController's viewControllers property explicitly with an NSArray. I haven't tried this but this should work:

When a user presses the "add" button, instead of just pushing the edit view controller, do something like:

```
NSArray* stack = navigationController.viewControllers;
navigationController.viewControllers = [stack arrayByAddingObject:rViewController];
[navigationController pushViewController:editController animated:YES];
```

(By the way, I would suggest not using names like "rView" except maybe for very short-lived local variables, like in a loop. Using descriptive names is very much part of the Cocoa idiom and will help you a lot in the long run.)